# How get xml or deserialized response from sudzc?

Tags: iphone, ios, xml, soap, sudzc

I just started some tests with sudzc on iOS iPhone app to access a soap service. I used sudzc with the link to the correct wsdl and downloaded the customized code.

Then I initialize the service with:

```
// Create the service
service = [EMLMagentoService service];
```

and open a session with:

```
// Returns NSString*
/* Login user and retrive session id */
SoapRequest *result=[service login:self action:@selector(loginHandler:) username: @"user.test" apiKey: @"GJGDWYgfgjgYGuueyfgue"];
```

that returns my session ID string... than I use that ID for the next call

```
// Handle the response from login.
- (void) loginHandler: (id) value {

    NSLog(@"##### loginHandler ######");

    // Handle errors
    if([value isKindOfClass:[NSError class]]) {
        NSLog(@"%@", value);
        return;
    }

    // Handle faults
    if([value isKindOfClass:[SoapFault class]]) {
        NSLog(@"%@", value);
        return;
    }

    NSString *sessionID = (NSString *)value;

    [service call:self action:@selector(callHandler:) sessionId:sessionID resourcePath:@"catalog_category.level" args:nil];

}

// Handle the response from call.
- (void) callHandler: (id) value {

    NSLog(@"##### callHandler ######");
    // Handle errors
    if([value isKindOfClass:[NSError class]]) {
        NSLog(@"%@", value);
        return;
    }

    // Handle faults
    if([value isKindOfClass:[SoapFault class]]) {
        NSLog(@"%@", value);
        return;
    }

    NSLog(@"Kind of class: %@",[value class]);
    NSLog(@"result:%@", value);
}
```

What I get is a string without any format... no xml... no array object...

```
##### loginHandler ######
 ##### callHandler ######
 Kind of class: __NSCFString
 result:category_id2parent_id1nameDefault Categoryis_active1position1level1
```

how can I get an xml or a deserialized object?